# Using process.start to create application instance does not allow me to read my.settings

Tags: vb.net

In the editor I am developing, clicking on the "New" menu creates another application process.

```
Process.Start(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

The problem is that this second process can't see any user settings in my.settings. My guess is that for some reason its not the same user. If my gut is correct, how can I do this using the same user account?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Process with My.Settings]

I've just tried whatever your code. That perfectly works on my machine even in another instance execution time. It can retrieve the app `My.Settings` data correctly.

[image: My.Settings Configuration]

If it fails, probably you should delete the `Local AppData` and try again. Otherwise, you need to provide more details if the problem persists.

> Alternatively, you can use `Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath)` to launch the app and create an instance of itself. It should work for you.

Comment: I will try clearing the local appdata. However, I'm now wondering if it has something to do with the user policy changes they made at my work. Let me see if that works.

Comment: Sure, check the last provided method too.

Comment: Application isnt available in WPF i think

Comment: I'm sorry, but you didn't mention anything about WPF in your question. That's the reason why I did provide the method for your issue.

Comment: Your fine. I appreciate the help! Sadly, this didnt work for me. I removed the local app and rebuilt it. Not sure what could be causing this problem.

Comment: It seems to work when running outside of Visual Studio. I swear one day I'm going to pull an Office space moment and quit my job to work construction. :)